# How to use the delim parameter from getline

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I need to make a program in witch I have to read a text from an input file(ifstream fin("input.in")) and store it until the program meets the "#" character. I know it should be doable using fin.getline, but I can't make the "delim" parameter work. I would find useful an explanation of how doe it work, and an example. I already read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), but I couldn't find an example with fin.getline.
This is what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
ifstream fin("cod.in");
ofstream fout("cod.out");
char chr[100];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    fin.getline(chr,'#');
    fout<<chr<<" ";
}
```

Comment: I added at the end what you asked

Comment: Read the documentation you quoted *carefully*, especially with regards to the parameters this function takes. Also consider using the global [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) for the convenience of loading into an `std::string` instead of a c-string